# Page loading issue in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

My website has a lot of menus and submenus in its index page and these submenus are loaded from the db.Ajax is used to load the submenus. So its taking a lot of time to load the full page. How will i reduce the loading time.I am using asp.net mvc3 and sql server 2008 database

Comment: There are a lot of factors that can affect your site's loading time. Have you tried using [mini-profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to tell what could be the bottleneck in your solution without actually seeing it, but it sounds that you can benefit greatly by doing [caching](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs), in ASP.NET MVC it's quite easy to do, here is another great [tutorial](http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/net4-caching-with-mvc/) on the subject. Oh and remember -> “There are 2 hard problems in computer science: caching, naming, and off-by-1 errors” ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that could be going wrong and causing your application to run slowly.

I’d recommend you turn the [trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) feature on because that will tell you what may be wrong. As Dimitar Dimitrov already mentioned you can try to cache the query in some way so you don’t have to retrieve it every time.

Another option would be to optimize the query so that it fetches all menus and submenus in one query.

But again, don’t do anything specifically until you’ve profiled your application to see where specifically is the issue.